# Using IF formula and filtering columns from a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using an `IF` formula in sheet `B` as shown in the pictures, if the value equals to `1` in column `L` of sheet `A` it returns the value in Column `A` from sheet `A` to Column `A` of sheet `B` in the same row.

However, I'm using filters in Sheet `A` so when I filter other columns in that sheet my existing values in sheet `B`disappear. I’m looking for feedback on how I can keep the values in Sheet `B` even when filtering the columns in sheet `A`.

Sheet `A`:

[image: Sheet A]

Sheet `B`:

[image: Sheet B]

Comment: There's something not right about this. Filtering the source data will not make any difference to the formula result on another sheet - the value in cells L7 and A7 are unchanged, even if they are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the values in Sheet B even when filtering columns in Sheet A, you can use a different formula that doesn't rely on filtering. One approach is to use the FILTER function along with the IF function in Sheet B. Here's an example of how you can modify your formula:

In Sheet B, instead of using an IF formula, you can use the FILTER function to retrieve the values from Sheet A based on the condition. Let's assume you want to populate Column A in Sheet B with the values from Column A in Sheet A, but only when the corresponding value in Column L in Sheet A is 1.

Here's the modified formula you can use in cell A2 of Sheet B:

```
=FILTER('Sheet A'!A:A, 'Sheet A'!L:L=1)
```

This formula will filter the values in Column A of Sheet A based on the condition in Column L and return only the values where the condition is met. The resulting filtered values will be displayed in Column A of Sheet B, even if you apply filters to other columns in Sheet A.

Make sure to adjust the sheet name ('Sheet A') and column references ('A:A', 'L:L') in the formula according to your actual sheet structure.

By using this approach, the values in Sheet B will remain unaffected by any filters applied in Sheet A, allowing you to retain the desired information.

Comment: Thanks @Mark what does "A:A" and "L:L" do? I'm getting error #REF!

Comment: You may also chenge the range of A column and L column on A sheet. Such as the sample of [A sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmjdy.jpg) and [B sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbezN.jpg), the formula can be `=FILTER(A!A2:A7,A!B2:B7=1)`.